# Problem with writing the output of kpsewhich to a file

Tags: shell-escape

I create in my folder a file "blub.temp" and then tried out the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{shellesc}
%correct small bug in shellesc:
\protected\def\ShellEscape{\immediate\write18 }
\begin{document}

\ShellEscape{kpsewhich article.cls    >> blub.temp}

\immediate\write18{kpsewhich book.cls >> blub.temp}


\end{document}
```

When I compile this (pdflatex on miktex, texlive 2015, texlive 2016) **without** shell-escape I see messages like this in the log-file

```
 runsystem(kpsewhich book.cls >> blub.temp)...executed safely (allowed).
```

But blub.temp has no content.

When I compile **with** --shell-escape I see messages like

```
 runsystem(kpsewhich book.cls >> blub.temp)...executed.
```

and blub.temp contains the both pathes.

How can it be that the command is executed but does nothing when `--shell-escape` is not used? Can one correct this?

### Edit

As confirmed on the texlive list, redirections (`>`, `>>`) don't work in restricted mode. So the question is if there is any other way to catch the output of kpsewhich (without pipes or --shell-escape) ...

Comment: `kpsewhich` is in the list of programs allowed in the restricted shell; but in this case it is not allowed to write files, as far as I can see. I guess that Karl Berry is the one who can answer this; probably output redirection is not allowed in the restricted shell.

Comment: @egreg: I will ask. I see some arguments why such redirections are disallowed, but I now wonder how to catch the output of kpsewhich ...

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179748/4427, but probably you already knew it

Comment: @egreg: Well it was my question ;-). Also I commented Heikos answer and the comment still stands: problematic in miktex.

Comment: Where is `shellesc` to be found? At least for me, CTAN search doesn't find it. This is weird because it is clearly in TeX Live. Is there a way to find these things on CTAN? I told it to search everything, including file names.

Comment: @cfr: in the latex-tools: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about Lua?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\directlua{
    local fp = io.popen("kpsewhich article.cls")
    local fh = io.open("blub.temp", "a")
    while true do
       local line = fp:read()
       if line == nil then
          break
       end
       fh:write(line, "\noexpand\n")
    end
    fh:close()
    fp:close()
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this works but I can't currently remember if lua was an option ;-).