# How to check from LaTeX whether a pfb file exists?

Tags: fonts, external-files, kpathsea

I need to write a `tex` file which checks whether certain files can be found by `kpathsea` library.  It is easy to check whether a `sty` or an `fd file can be found:

```
 \IfFileExists{hyperref.sty}{Hyperref found}{Hyperref is not found}
 \IfFileExists{t1stix.fd}{Stix FD found }{Stix FD is not found}
```

However, I want to know whether, say, `stix-mathrm.pfb` can be found.  Of course, I can easily do this from command line, as

```
kpsewhich stix-mathrm.pfb
```

Well, I can use `write18` to call this command from a TeX file, but I wonder if there is a simpler way to do it.

*Update:* Ok, I probably should explain better what do I want.  I want to check whether an installation of TeX is good enough for `acmart` to work.  I know how to check the existence of style files and their versions.

What sometimes happens is that a user has incomplete font installation:  `fd` and and `sty` are present, but the fonts themselves are absent.  I need to check whether this is the case.

Since the check must be run by a user, I cannot rearrange file locations, input path, *or* use `write18` because many users just do not know how to enable it.

Ideally I want a `tex` file which produces a pdf that says:  "You have a good enough `hyperref`, but you lack `libertine` fonts.  Please install them from .."

Well, I guess I need to parse log file then :(

*Update 2:* . Silly me.  `kpsewhich` *is* enabled in `write18` by default in TeXLive and MikTeX.  I thought it was not.

Sorry for asking a stupid question.

Comment: See this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179748/2388 and also this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306987/problem-with-writing-the-output-of-kpsewhich-to-a-file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `catchfile`, whose interface is simpler than `\read`. This doesn't require shell escape (works with the restricted shell), but might not work in MiKTeX (sorry, can't test).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfExistsInTeXTrees}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \CatchFileDef{\temp}{"|kpsewhich #1"}{\endlinechar=\m@ne}%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \ifx\temp\@empty
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\IfExistsInTeXTrees{stix-mathrm.pfb}{YES}{NO}

\IfExistsInTeXTrees{funny.pfb}{YES}{NO}

\end{document}
```

An `expl3` implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prg_new_protected_conditional:Nnn \boris_if_exists_in_tex_trees:n { T,F,TF }
 {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich~#1 } { \endlinechar=-1 } \l__boris_if_exists_temp_tl
  \tl_if_blank:VTF \l__boris_if_exists_temp_tl
   {
    \prg_return_false:
   }
   {
    \prg_return_true:
   }
 }
\tl_new:N \l__boris_if_exists_temp_tl
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfExistsInTeXTreesTF \boris_if_exists_in_tex_trees:nTF
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfExistsInTeXTreesT \boris_if_exists_in_tex_trees:nT
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfExistsInTeXTreesF \boris_if_exists_in_tex_trees:nF

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\IfExistsInTeXTreesTF{stix-mathrm.pfb}{YES}{NO}

\IfExistsInTeXTreesT{stix-mathrm.pfb}{YES}

\IfExistsInTeXTreesTF{funny.pfb}{YES}{NO}

\IfExistsInTeXTreesF{funny.pfb}{NO}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Boris This requires nothing special from the user (I'm just unsure about MiKTeX).

Comment: Is `kpsewhich` enabled by default in `write18`?  I thought not...

Comment: The programs that can be run in the restricted shell escape currently are `bibtex`, `bibtex8`, `extractbb`, `gregorio`, `kpsewhich`, `makeindex`, `repstopdf` and `texosquery-jre8`. Also the last one might be a candidate for your purpose, but requires a Java VM installed on the user's system.

Comment: It works with miktex too (both examples).

Comment: Note that `expl3` solution should be modified to incorporate [more recent changes to expl3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474897/119566)

Comment: @John Fixed with the current method. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to avoid shell-escape to enable you to run `kpsewhich` an alternative might be to put the fonts in the tex inputpath so you can use IfFileExists

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\IfFileExists{stix-mathrm.pfb}{\show\yes}{\show\no}

\end{document}
```

This says no with the default path

```
$ pdflatex pp446
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./pp446.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.13> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./pp446.aux)
> \no=undefined.
\reserved@a ->\show \no 

l.5 ...xists{stix-mathrm.pfb}{\show\yes}{\show\no}

?
```

but yes if you adjust the paths to append the type1 font path to the standard input path

```
$ TEXINPUTS=:\$T1FONTS pdflatex pp446
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./pp446.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.13> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./pp446.aux)
> \yes=undefined.
\reserved@a ->\show \yes 

l.5 ...xists{stix-mathrm.pfb}{\show\yes}{\show\no}

?
```