# xsim: LaTeX3 Error: File '' not found

Tags: xsim

Below is a minimalized template I have been using without any trouble for quite some time (**Edit:** Simplified the code and updated the error message). It no longer runs on my system. I do not know if it's a problem with the `xsim` package, with one of its dependencies or just some weird local issue that should not be happening. I have updated my `texlive` installation. I'm on `MacOS High Sierra`. I am compiling with `pdflatex` Any ideas?

The error message I get:

```
! LaTeX3 Error: File '' not found.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{QuestionBank.tex}
\begin{question}[ID={Q001}, points={10}, tags={easy}]
First Question: Select one of the following solutions:
\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
Solution to First Question
\end{answer}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand*\includeQuestion[1]{%
  \XSIMexpandcode{\printexercise{question}{\GetExerciseIdForProperty{ID}{#1}}}%
}

\newcommand*\includeSolution[1]{%
  \XSIMexpandcode{\printsolution{question}{\GetExerciseIdForProperty{ID}{#1}}}%
}

\DeclareExerciseType{question}{
    exercise-env = question,
    solution-env = answer,
    exercise-name = question, % used with headings=true
    solution-name = solution,  % used with headings=true
    exercise-template = default,
    solution-template = default,
}

\DeclareExerciseCollection{myCollection}

\begin{document}

\collectexercises{myCollection}
\input{QuestionBank.tex}
\collectexercisesstop{myCollection}

\includeQuestion{Q001}
\includeSolution{Q001}

\end{document}
```

Comment: On my Windows machine (with MikTeX) `aux` is not allowed as a folder name. With `blub` or a different name I can get things to compile. Later on I get a `! LaTeX3 Error: File '' not found.` which doesn't look right. Do things work if you set `path = {},`? I don't know about the security settings of TeX live on a Mac, but maybe TeX is not allowed to write in the directory.

Comment: You have to first create the `aux` subfolder, TeX will not create it. About the empty file name I don't know.

Comment: @moewe, @egreg, you're both right. Thanks! I have edited the question. In my haste I prepared a minimal example and forgot to create the ``aux`` directory. With the ``aux`` directory created, I get the ``! LaTeX3 Error: File '' not found.`` error. And that is new.

Comment: @moewe, for me same thing whether the directory is called ``aux`` or ``blub``.

Comment: The problem is associated with ``\includeSolution{Q001}``: If I comment that line out, the error message disappears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to a bug in `\tl_set_from_file:Nnn`, which has been deprecated and replaced by `\file_get:nnN` in `expl3`. A mistake in the order of arguments leads to the erroneous result. It will be fixed shortly, for the present try

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \tl_set_from_file:Nnn #1#2#3
  { \file_get:nnN {#3} {#2} #1 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: I'm suddenly having problems with this again, but very likely caused by something else. I'll link the questions with this comment. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617147/xsim-question-counter-does-not-print